# Putting Android into airplane mode with adb hack

Tags: java, android

With Macrodroid, adb shell pm grant com.arlosoft.macrodroid android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS can put it into airplane mode when you give this permission. My code

`boolean isEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1; Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);`

In my own application, when I give that permission, I can change the settings to airplane mode, but when I publish the intent state change, I get permission denied.

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);  intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);  context.sendBroadcast(intent);`

How can Macrodroid do this?

Toggle airplane mode